# cant save a test case in Selenium IDE when I reference the user-extension.js error shows [javascript application] error: TypeError: def is undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, undefined, selenium-ide

I'm using a user-extension.js file to store code and use in my test cases.  I can run the test case and the randomstring generator populates the webpage correctly but when I go to save the test case I get a

```
[javascript application] error: TypeError: def is undefined
```

And an empty file is saved.

I've tried 4 different types of randomizing code that works for other people and they all work but fail to save in the same way.  Below is the latest one.

any ideas why its unable to save?

Comment: you're trying to save the test case, test suite or the user-extensions?

Comment: I'm trying to just save the test case thats utilizing the user-extension.